# Hosting website on remoter IIS server, Cannot Insert into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, iis

Using a remote server to host a website on IIS for work. Using SQL Server that's on another server at work but I cannot get them to play along.

```
connectionString="Data Source=Stuff;Initial Catalog=dbApprentices; User id=****; password=****"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

I get no error. Everything works fine when I use Visual Studio.

Comment: Your connection string is fine. There's not a ton of detail in the question to go on. When you say everything works fine in visual studio - is that also the machine that sql server is on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who run into this problem. I had to create an application pool and set the identity to the user who has access to the sql database.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 One of the well known differences.

Answer (score 0):

OK,

this is the connection string i use on my web servers..

Server=sqlserver\instance;Database=databasename;User ID=username;Password=password;

ensure the web server has visibility to the sql server (and can access the ports the sql is published on)